# Does LINQ to objects stop processing Any() when condition is true?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Consider the following:

```
bool invalidChildren = this.Children.Any(c => !c.IsValid());
```

This class has a collection of child objects that have an `IsValid()` method. Suppose that the `IsValid()` method is a processor intensive task. After encountering the first child object where `IsValid()` is `false`, theoretically processing can stop because the result can never become true. Does LINQ to objects actually stop evaluating after the first `IsValid() = false` (like a logical AND) or does it continue evaluating all child objects?

Obviously I could just put this in a foreach loop and break on the first invalid result, but I was just wondering if LINQ to objects is smart enough to do this as well.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers, for some reason I didn't think to look it up on MSDN myself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes it does.  As soon as it finds a match, the criteria is satified.  `All` is similar in that it checks all items but if one doesn't match it ends immeditately as well.

`Exists` works in the same manner too.

[Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

[Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx)

> The elements of the current List are individually passed to the Predicate delegate, and processing is stopped when a match is found.

[All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

etc...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it stops as soon as the results can be evaluated.  Here's a quick proof:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool allvalid = TestClasses().Any(t => !t.IsValid());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestClass> TestClasses()
        {
            yield return new TestClass() { IsValid = () => { Console.Write(string.Format("TRUE{0}",Environment.NewLine)); return true; } };
            yield return new TestClass() { IsValid = () => { Console.Write(string.Format("FALSE{0}", Environment.NewLine)); return false; } };
            yield return new TestClass() { IsValid = () => { Console.Write(string.Format("TRUE{0}", Environment.NewLine)); return true; } };
            yield return new TestClass() { IsValid = () => { Console.Write(string.Format("TRUE{0}", Environment.NewLine)); return true; } };
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public Func<bool> IsValid {get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will stop after it encounters the first item for which the condition matches, in your case the first item for which `c.IsValid()` returns `false`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

> The enumeration of source is stopped
>   as soon as the result can be
>   determined.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty empirical test to see for yourself:

```
class Kebab
{
    public static int NumberOfCallsToIsValid = 0;

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        NumberOfCallsToIsValid++;
        return false;
    }
}

...

var kebabs = new Kebab[] { new Kebab(), new Kebab() };
kebabs.Any(kebab => !kebab.IsValid());

Debug.Assert(Kebab.NumberOfCallsToIsValid == 1);
```

The result is that yes, the `Any` LINQ operator stops as soon as a collection item matches the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

as per [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx),

The enumeration of *source* is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.